# Drawing weighted, directional graphs in Unity

Tags: c#, graph, unity-game-engine, weighted-graph

I am attempting to build a project that allows users to build a flow network and then solve for the maximum flow of the network using Unity. I thought that a graph drawing library would already exist but I'm unable to find it.

As I am relatively new to Unity, my questions are:

1. Is there a library for drawing weighted, directional graphs in Unity?
2. If such a library doesn't exist, can anyone recommend some useful tutorials that deal with drawing simple 2d structures (nodes and edges of a graph) in Unity?

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Unity; I suggest that you look into the [Line renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) first, it's a relatively simple interface for drawing weighted graphs.

But, if you wanted to draw primitive lines, you could look at [OpenGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html) lines.

[This](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/basics/building-a-graph/) tutorial also might also be useful in developing intuitive graphs, mind you it doesn't use the Line renderer but the same principles when dealing with Vectors still apply.

I've also used [Vectrosity](https://starscenesoftware.com/vectrosity.html) for rapid prototyping (NOTE: I'm in no way tethered to this product).